# Xcode 5 Loading a URL in a new View Controller with a WebView in it

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, webview, xcode5

It seems that all the methods in earlier versions of Xcode are not working for me.

What I have right now:
I have a main menu with a button that segues into another view with a different controller with a WebView in it (has a property so the URL to load can be set)

What I want:
When I load that view from that button I want to pass a string from the first view to the new view that represents the URL and load it in the web view.  Basically I want a generic WebView view that can load different URLs passed by the views that segue to it.

Here is the code for the WebView H file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BRWebView : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UIWebView *requestWebView;

}
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *loadUrl;

@end
```

In the ViewController for the MainMenu there is this for the button listener

```
-(IBAction)requestButton:(id)sender
{
    BRWebView *web = [self.storyboard    instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BRWebView"];
    web.loadUrl = @"Websitename.com";
    [self presentModalViewController:web animated:YES];

}
```

And in the BRWebView.m file there is this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:_loadUrl];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [requestWebView loadRequest:request];
}
```

Comment: Sure, I need to get on my machine real quick.

Comment: I add an answer, you need to set up the good name of your property and your second view controller. (I consider to pass a string for your URL but you can pass a URL or whatever).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT after code in the question :**

In the `ViewController` replace your code by :

```
- (IBAction)requestButton:(id)sender
{
    BRWebView *web = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BRWebView"];
    web.loadUrl = @"http://websitename.com";
    [self presentViewController:web animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

and in the `BRWebView.m` remove your code in *viewDidLoad* and add *viewWillAppear* :

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // URL Request Object
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_loadUrl]];

    // Load the request in the UIWebView
    [_requestWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

**Old answer :**

You need to pass your URL data with a property like this *(without navigation controller)* :

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) 
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        ViewControllerB *viewControllerB = segue.destinationViewController;

        // Pass URL
        viewControllerB.webviewURL = @"http://myurl.com";
    }
}
```

*with navigation controller :*

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) 
    {
        UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        ViewControllerB *viewControllerB = (ViewControllerB *)navController.topViewController;

        // Pass URL
        viewControllerB.webviewURL = @"http://myurl.com";
    }
}
```

On your **second view .h** :

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *webviewURL;
```

**second view .m** :

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // URL Request Object
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_webviewURL]];

    // Load the request in the UIWebView
    [self.webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a crash on  ViewControllerB *viewControllerB = (ViewControllerB *)navController.topViewController; at the moment, not sure on specifics.

Comment: I'll edit my answer to be in accordance with the code of your question

Comment: Okay... Apparently I'm still getting a crash on the BRWebView object creation.  "NSInvalidArgumentException" "Storyboard does not contain a view controller with identifier BRWebView"  Tried changing to request web view.  I seem to have everything linked up correctly not sure what is going wrong

Comment: you need to add `BRWebView` as identifier of your view in the storyboard

Comment: Okay yes! Thank you.  Now one more thing.  How do I get my Navigation controller to show up at the top of that page?

Comment: `- (IBAction)requestButton:(id)sender` need to be change with my last answer embedded a navigation controller

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean by that? Really sorry.

Comment: I explained how to do with a navigation controller in my answer `with navigation controller :`

Comment: BRWebView *viewControllerB = (BRWebView*)navController.topViewController; crashes now
2013-10-09 17:28:16.451 Book Raider[3811:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[BRWebView topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x109520ea0'

Comment: Solved! segue.destinationViewController is not a type of UINavigationController.  What I want to get is the next view controller which is my BRWebView. So the code is:              BRWebView * WebViewCon = (BRWebView *)[segue destinationViewController];
WebViewCon.loadUrl = @"http://library.ttu.edu/services/circulation/request_item_mobile.php"; in the prepare for segue

Answer (score 2):

You should set the URL(NSString) property before perform the segue to your destination view controller, and load the request on the 'viewWillAppear' callback:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if (self.loadUrl) {
        [self.requestWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.loadUrl]]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is basically what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

//Easy code for web view

```
- (void)viewDidLoad { 
    [super viewDidLoad]; // self.myWebView.delegate=self; 
    NSString   *urlString=@"http://www.google.com"; 
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *obj=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; 
    [self.myWebView loadRequest:obj]; // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib. 
}
```

Comment: could you format visually a bit better your answer?